# How can I Use fancybox to pop up an edit form with existing values filled in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a table of data that the user may want to edit. I have an edit button and fancybox launching an inline based.

I would like the fancy box to contain a form filled with the values from the current table. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple different ways... if the data to edit is in the table you can use the 'inline content' option...

```
<a id="inline" href="#data">This shows content of element who has id="data"</a>

<div style="display:none"><div id="data">FORM HTML</div></div>
```

Then ectract the data from the table and fill the form using javascript...

or you can use the 'ajax' option...

```
<a href="http://www.example/data.php">This takes content using ajax</a>
```

where data.php returns the form filled out with thedata fetched from the server

Comment: not if the content is the same, can just use one form over and over
I'm assuming 'That' is reffering to the first option

Comment: What im stuck on is extracting from the table and filling the form using javascript.

Comment: would need to see the code, I can only guess at your implementation...I'm thinking you'll need a more complex setup than what it is out of the box...you'll likely find answers here...
http://fancybox.net/api
if it were me I would use the ajax method, so then you can set a query param ?id=idofcontent to get the correct data